# Click location in iframe relative to whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

## Problem

I have a page with several iframes, and a single Javascript file that is loaded in every frame. I register a `.click()` function to record usage. I'm trying to find the x/y position of a click relative to the entire browser window. Screen x/y doesn't work if the browser moves, and page x/y or client x/y gives the position relative to the frame.

## Question

I need to do more processing within the frame, so is there a way to get the x/y position of the click relative to the browser using only javascript in the frame?

Comment: You might be coming up against the same-origin policy. Scripts on the main page do not have access to the content of iframes on the page if the frame source is from a different origin.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, the main page and the frame are served from the same place. I'm actually trying to go the other way: with javascript running inside the frame, get the position over the whole page.